# What kind of track light is this?

Tags: lighting

I have a broken dimmable track light, and I am looking for a replacement for the track. But I couldn't identify what kind of track it is. It has 3 parallel tracks and 4 wires are connected to one end as in the attached photo (the black wire is not connected to anything). It doesn't fit any standard track type (J, H, or L). Anyone has some idea about this?

If it is not possible to find an exact replacement, what kind of track can I attach to these wires?

[image: Track light]
[image]

Comment: Adding a country would be good to help decode what the wires are at least supposed to be.

Comment: There are four wires, but it looks like the black isn't connected to anything.  Is that true?

Comment: I am living in Finland. And yes the black one isn't connected to anything. The green/yellow one is connected though (it is not quite clear from the photo).

Comment: I see brown, blue, white, black, and yellow - five wires.

Comment: You are right. I will update the question. Brown, blue, white and yellow/green wires are connected, while the black one isn't.

Comment: Have you asked a local lighting specialist? This might be something that was only sold in finland.

Comment: @Jasen that'd probably be the case.

Comment: By the way, sorry for using lower case on your country Finland above, that was unintentional.